Perl to find AND replace IP address in a string
I need help for a Perl script to find and replace an IP address saved to a string or in a file, if an IP address is present.
Apologies first - I don't have a development/software background but have managed to update and modify the few Perl scripts that have fallen in my lap by research and trial and error. I was hesitant to post, however, the solution to this programming task simply eludes me.
I have seen a few examples of finding and extracting an IP address, see below for an example using . But I haven't figured out how to apply to Regexp::Common:net to read from a string or a file.
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;
use Regexp::Common qw/net/;

my $Event_text="This is a test string with an IP address 10.10.10.20"

while (<DATA>)
{
    print $1, "\n" if /($RE{net}{IPv4})/;
}

__DATA__
10.10.10.10

Executing this does return '10.10.10.10' and it ignores non-valid IPs but I still need the script to:
(a) search in a string already saved to a variable or a file (one or the other - doesn't matter)
(b) somehow replace this IP address with some other string, like X.X.X.X within the given string or file (again, one or the other). I assume this can be done with a Perl search and replace regexp - which is another matter.
The Perl script I tested works but it's only a portion of what I need and was really just to understand how the Regexp::Common (net) module works.

If you want to read from a file or stdin, change <DATA> to <>. And like ikegami says, use substitution operator s//// to change it.

In your deleted answer, you left out word boundary characters \b, that is why you got a partial match.

Regex-based replacements can be performed using the substitution operator, s///.
For example, the following would replace all IP addresses with 192.168.10.10.
s/$RE{net}{IPv4}/192.168.10.10/g

This is short for
s/$RE{net}{IPv4}/ "192.168.10.10" /eg

If you don't want to replace with a static address, you can replace the replacement expression with any other you wish. $& contains matched address. So, for example, you can do something like
my %mapping = (
   "10.10.10.10" => "192.168.10.10",
   # ...
);

s{
   $RE{ net }{ IPv4 }
}{
   $mapping{ $& } // $&
}xeg


Note that this answer assumes the string to match is in $_, a.k.a. the topic variable. If it is in some random variable $foo you will need to bind the substitution to that variable with $foo =~ s{ $RE{net}{IPv4} }{ $mapping{$&} // $& }xeg.

I made a small change to a suggested substitution to ensure that only valid IP addresses are substituted:  $Event_text =~ s/\b$RE{net}{IPv4}\b/ "X.X.X.X" /eg;
